# Full text search in mongodb in Symfony 3.4

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to use full text search in mongodb:

`db.Product.createIndex({"name": "text"})` 
`db.Product.find({$text: {$search: "xxxxx"}})`

how to use this in controller to symfony?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: $odm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager');
$repo = $odm->getRepository(Product::class);
$query = array('text' => 'name', 'search'=> 'XXXX');
$resultSet = $repo->find($query);

Comment: the `find` method expects an id to work. Did you try `findBy($query)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. In summary, the controller for the search engine looks like the following:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
  public function searchBarAction()
  {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('search', TextType::class)
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Components:_searchBar.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
 }

/**
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function handleSearchAction(Request $request)
{

    $searchData = $request->query->get('form')['search'];


    $dbName = 'ece';
    $connection = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getConnection();
    $mongo = $connection->getMongo();
    $db = $mongo->selectDB($dbName);

    $resultSetProduct = $db->Product->find([
        '$text' => ['$search' => $searchData]
    ]);

    $resultSet = $db->MainData->find([
        '$text' => ['$search' => $searchData]
    ]);

    $itemProduct =  $resultSetProduct->count();
    $itemSet = $resultSet->count() + $itemProduct;


    return $this->render('search/index.html.twig', [
        'searchData' => $searchData,
        'resultSetProduct' => $resultSetProduct,
        'itemProduct' => $itemProduct,
        'itemSet' => $itemSet,
        'resultSet' => $resultSet

    ]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all create Product entity(adjust to your needs)

```
<?php

/**
 * @Document
 * @Index(keys={"name"="text"})
 */
class Product
{
    /** @Id */
    public $id;

    /** @Field(type="string") */
    public $name;

    /** @Field(type="float") */
    public $price;
}
```

Look at `$name` and `@Index` annotation

Then use query builder text() method

```
// Run a text search against the index
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Product')
    ->text('words you are looking for');
```

More info you can find [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/query-builder-api.html#text-search)

The other way is to create native query with expr() from doctrine query builder